# Bulk Mail - Anti spam measures

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mailing-list

We are providing a bulk mail system for a couple of our CRM/B2B customers, 
But on one of our smaller runs we got back a number of spam related bounce backs.

I have read that we would need to set up a PTR record on the clients website DNS to point to our server in order to help this, Is there anything else that i can do or am i barking up the wrong tree completely?

Comment: Some bounce backs include a message indicating *why* they were bounced.  What did these ones say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have SPF,DomainKeys,DKIM,PTR Record and proper mx record for your mail server .
Apart from this you should try to whitelist your mail server with Other email providers like
yahoo,Gmail,Hotmail,Comcast. Though you should have some throttle at your end on domain basis not to get in blacklist of other email serivice provider.

Answer (score 0):

You should read MailChimp's guide here: http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/email-delivery-for-it-professionals/ which details the issues you might come across and how to get around them.